# Refresh a .phtml file when product added to cart

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart, phtml

When you add an item to cart the mini cart `cart.phtml` data is refreshed with the new data.

What I want is for `another .phtml` data to be refreshed when an item is added to the cart `(catalog/product/view/type/default)` to be exact.

Can this be done?

Comment: Are you using AJAX ? If so you have to fetch `catalog/product/view/type/default` data along with `mini cart` data

Comment: Yes. How can this be done. Please help

Comment: You have to provide more details, like: how you are fetching AJAX data ? the format of response ? the place where you are creating response ?